# python point indices in KDTree

Tags: python, scipy, kdtree

Given a list of points, how can I get their indices in a KDTree?

```
from scipy import spatial
import numpy as np

#some data
x, y = np.mgrid[0:3, 0:3]
data = zip(x.ravel(), y.ravel())

points = [[0,1], [2,2]]

#KDTree
tree = spatial.cKDTree(data)

# incices of points in tree should be [1,8]
```

I could do something like:

```
[tree.query_ball_point(i,r=0) for i in points]

>>> [[1], [8]]
```

Does it make sense to do it that way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`cKDTree.query(x, k, ...)`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.0/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.cKDTree.query.html#scipy.spatial.cKDTree.query) to find the *k* nearest neighbours to a given set of points `x`:

```
distances, indices = tree.query(points, k=1)
print(repr(indices))
# array([1, 8])
```

---

In a trivial case such as this, where your dataset and your set of query points are both small, and where each query point is identical to a single row within the dataset, it would be faster to use simple boolean operations with broadcasting rather than building and querying a k-D tree:

```
data, points = np.array(data), np.array(points)
indices = (data[..., None] == points.T).all(1).argmax(0)
```

`data[..., None] == points.T` broadcasts out to an `(nrows, ndims, npoints)` array, which could quickly become expensive in terms of memory for larger datasets. In such cases you might get better performance out of a normal `for` loop or list comprehension:

```
indices = [(data == p).all(1).argmax() for p in points]
```